# Babylon objects not executing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babylonjs

I am having a weird problem. I am developing a react project that uses Babylonjs. On that project I am able to load objects into the scene. However, when I try to create a Material, in this case a PBR Material, it looks like the browser does not process the instantiation of the material. Problem is the following:

```
import ConnectionConstants from "../../Constants/ConnectionConstants.js";
import { PBRMaterial, Texture } from "@babylonjs/core";
import "@babylonjs/loaders";

function MaterialLoader(object, material, scene) {
  debugger;
  let pbrMaterial = new PBRMaterial("mat", scene);
  debugger;
```

When I call MaterialLoader the browser hits the first debugger, but **doesn't** hit the second debugger. Basicly, all code south `let pbrMaterial = new PBRMaterial("mat", scene);` does not get executed.

Any clues why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed! Turns out scene was null, and no error was being displayed by the PBRMaterial.